# Newbie jQuery toggle/hide/show on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a function using jQuery, but my jQuery is not good at all. When the page loads there should be two fields `Min Apt Price` and `Max Apt Price`. When I click a button, those initial fields need to hide and I need `Min Bed Price` and `Max Bed Price` to display. I have gotten to the point where when the page loads the `Min Apt Price` and `Max Apt Price` will display and the other two remain hidden. When I click the button the `Min Bed Price` and `Max Bed Price` will display, but next to the original fields. Hope that makes sense.

HTML:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.room-price').hide();
      $('#price-switch').click(function() {
        $('.room-price').toggle();
        $('.apt-price').hide();
      });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="price-switch">Switch</button>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="apt-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Apt Price" id="minimum-price">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Apt Price" id="maximum-price">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="room-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Bed Price" id="min-room-price">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Bed Price" id="max-room-price">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `apt-price` as an ID, not a class, so if you wanted to just toggle them, you'd do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.room-price').hide();
    
    $('#price-switch').click(function() {
        $('.room-price, #apt-price').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="price-switch">Switch</button>
<div class="row">
    <div id="apt-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Apt Price" id="minimum-price">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Apt Price" id="maximum-price">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="room-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Bed Price" id="min-room-price">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Bed Price" id="max-room-price">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oy. Always something small I look over. Thanks! I appreciate your answer and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Its `Id=apr-price` is not class so apply with `$('#apt-price')`.Apply both in single toggle its enough to switch

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.room-price').hide();
      $('#price-switch').click(function() {
        $('.room-price ,#apt-price').toggle();
   
      });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="price-switch">Switch</button>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="apt-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Apt Price" id="minimum-price">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Apt Price" id="maximum-price">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="room-price">
        <div class="col-sm-2 min-max-price">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Min Bed Price" id="min-room-price">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="general-text-field" placeholder="Max Bed Price" id="max-room-price">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```